# dev server returned error code 403 react native

Tags: android, windows, react-native

Followed the steps [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) to try react-native android on a windows box.

1. On a separate prompt I executed **react-native start** which is running fine
2. Started the AVD from AVD Manager
3. Executed **react-native run-android**

*BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 27.632 secs
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (D:\software\Android\android-sdk/platform-tool
s/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }*

4. Executed **react-native run-android** on a separate console from within same folder

But I see an error which I'm having hard time to resolve. Please suggest resolution.

[image]
[image]

**---EDIT---**

Possibly the issue is that 8081 port is in use by McAfee. So I updated the server.js to run dev port on 8088 and now when I browse ***http://localhost:8088/index.android.bundle?platform=android*** I can see JS loading.

**But how do I make android use this address instead of default **10.0.2.2:8081**?** I found a file AndroidInfoHelpers.java which contains that 10.0.2.2 path but not sure if that's the way as being a JAVA file I possibly need to recompile whole program. There should be a simpler way to point android app to use a different port for dev server.

Also, when I execute **react-native run-android** the first line that gets output says "JS Server not recognized.. Continuing with the build" which likely is shouting the same thing.

Comment: Dont forget this step also: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi

Comment: Thanks. However, The link seems to be for case when running app on real device whereas I'm trying on emulator within same box..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**A)** Set the new port for dev server 
User command 
**react-native start --port=8088** 
or 
 yourproject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\server.js
to set the the available port say 8080

now use **react-native start** to start server on 8080

 
**B)** Now to establish communication between emulator and dev server, use below command
**adb -s emulator -5554 reverse tcp:8088 tcp:8088**
 i) 5554 =>emulator port (**adb devices** command will tell you emulator port but if this command is not working then set the path C:/../android-sdk/platform-tools in **Path** environemnt variable )
 
ii) 8088 =>server port

**C)** run the command **react-native run-android**

**D)** Follow below steps updating Dev server path in emulator

i) Ctrl + M for windows to open your dev menu for the emulator. 
ii) Click Dev Settings 
III) Under Debugging select Debug server host & port for device 
IV) Enter the url and port for your application as 10.0.2.2:8088

Comment: this should be a accepeted as answer.

Comment: Perfect solution, It worked for me because 8081 port blocked by McAfee

Answer (score 5):

1. Press `cmd + M` (`Ctrl + M` for windows) to open your dev menu for the emulator (Please make sure your react-native app is open in the active window of the android emulator before using this command)
2. Click `Dev Settings`
3. Under `Debugging` select `Debug server host & port for device`
4. Enter the correct url and port for your application in your case `10.0.2.2:8088`

Once you do that you can reload your application and it should work.

Comment: Cmd+M (I guess Ctrl+M) on Emulator only shows WallPapers, Widget & Settings. When I drill settings, I just see AutoRotate.

Answer (score 1):

1) First set the port number as `8088` in below file

```
yourproject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\server.js
```

now build the project.

2) Follow below steps updating Dev server path in emulator

- Ctrl + M for windows to open your dev menu for the emulator.
- Click Dev Settings
- Under Debugging select Debug server host & port for device
- Enter the  url and port for your application as 10.0.2.2:8088

Answer (score 1):

This issue might occur because of the blockage of default port. In my case, I was able to fix it after executing following steps-

1. Start dev server on a new port:-
   **react-native start --port=8088**
2. Open developer menu by vibrating on actual connected device or pressing '**Ctrl + M**' on emulator.
3. Select **Dev Settings**
4. Under Debugging select Debug server host & port for device
5. Enter the url and port for your application as '**10.0.2.2:8088**'

Answer (score 0):

Just run this one your phone, it is a waste of time to try to figure out the hard coded React code for the emulator. It just does not seem like enough time was spent fixing this issue. Spent 3 days on reading way to many blogs, and trying way to many things and nothing worked. Our company also runs McAfee and I had the same issue.

Comment: I am using phone but still its not working and i am getting same 403 error code on dead red screen. if any other solution you have plz let us know ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Does the same thing but quick.

Just set the port when run the app

`react-native run-android --port=8082`