# react-native init on Android device: Development server error code 403 error

Tags: reactjs, server, react-native

I am new to develop apps with react native and I have a problem.
I followed the "Getting started" guide on the official documentation but I have a problem.

I wrote these commands:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

And yesterday worked just fine! But today, when I want to reload the app, it doesn't work and I get back this error:

> The development server returned response error code: 403"
>   Url: http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false
>   ...

How can I fix it? Is some permission problem? But yesterday worked!

Thanks.
Giovanni.

Comment: Duplicate question. Check the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56251822/4556035

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this.

The problem is that the device is on the same wireless network of my pc **and** is connected via USB.

Once I turned off the wi-fi (or use the tip in this url [dev server returned error code 403 react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376512/dev-server-returned-error-code-403-react-native/37667876#37667876)) it works fine.

Thanks everybody!