# ignite-jhipster does't work with backend Jhipster

Tags: react-native, jhipster

I follow this tutorial https://jruddell.com/blog/ignite-jhipster.

I create backend and start it, i create the frontend and push the app on a device (avd), i try to login with user/user, it doesn't work, but on web http://localhost:8080/ it works well.

AppConfig.js

```
export default {
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
  appUrlScheme: 'mobile',
  // font scaling override - RN default is on
  allowTextFontScaling: true
}
```

The react-native config changed ? And how can i see the logs with ignite-jhispter ?

Thanks you

Comment: Can you access http://localhost:8080 from your device's browser?  You may need to specify your computer's local network IP if not

Comment: No i can't access to localhost:8080 from my avd, how i can confgure that ?

Comment: I usually use my computer's local IP.  You can also use `10.0.2.2:8080` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310592/3737815

Comment: I can access on avd's browser with 10.0.2.2:8080, so i replace 'apiUrl' in the AppConfig.js, but the app launch in the avd can't login. Someone can try the tutorial please ?

Comment: You're right, 10.0.2.2 doesn't work either.  Using your computer's local IP works though.  I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found it :D

After launching the android emulator:

```
adb reserve tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

I must specify the port when i run the app:

```
react-native run-android --port 8080
```

And of course, as you said, use this IP 10.0.2.2 in AppConfig.js

```
export default {
  apiUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8080',
  appUrlScheme: 'mobile',
  allowTextFontScaling: true
}
```

It works on my avd now.

Comment: The `--port` flag starts the React Native packager on that port, I don't think it's doing what you expect.

Comment: I have another problem, the can't update when i press twice 'R', it call http://10.0.2.2:8181/index.delta?[...]. The port 8181 is already used by McAfee.

Comment: Try using `--port 8083`, 8080 is used by your backend and the default port for the React Native packager is 8081 but that is in use by McAfee https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB66797

Comment: It works with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376512/dev-server-returned-error-code-403-react-native

Answer (score 1):

When you start your JHipster backend, it displays the local and external IPs that your app is reachable at.  Copy the External IP and use that as your API url.  `http://localhost:8080` will work with the iOS emulator, but not the Android emulator as it has its own loopback service.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'backend' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://10.0.0.113:8080 <- Use this as your apiUrl for Android
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i use the avd, It's possible to see the URL called by the app ?
Running C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Comment: As mentioned in the Ignite JHipster readme, I recommend using Reactotron for debugging, logs, and network requests https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/tree/v1.x.  You would need to configure the IP in ReactotronConfig.js as well.  Otherwise, use the standard React Native debugging tools https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: react-native can't access to localhost server

Comment: The external IP shows an IP, not localhost.  I verified this solution on an android emulator

Comment: any IP doesn't work too, it seems a react-native know problem on android emulator, but IOS works well.