# React Native using android emulator

Tags: react-native

I'am just starting with react native using Android emulator on windows. When I follow the react native getting started tutorial and run the app I see 'unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle' error and fixed it by following these steps as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows) :

> (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets react-native
>
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

This worked good - App.js renders ok, but I am now unable to see any changes made to the code in the emulator (I have tried running npm-start and react-native run-android but no luck). When I hit reload button in the emulator (RR) I see this error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwjI6.png)

I have also tried resetting cache(react-native start --reset-cache) and no luck.

How could I get my changes refreshed in the app please and fix this error? Thanks :)

Comment: Try navigating to `android` folder and run `gradlew clean` command

Comment: did that, still see the same output

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376512/dev-server-returned-error-code-403-react-native